# Export a database query to OPML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, opml

Is there a way to export a database query to OPML?

Comment: Your preference is for an Access or MSSQL answer? What do you mean by "Access"? Access the database front end, or do you mean the default database engine, i.e., Jet/ACE? And why don't you must edit your question to reflect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [SQL Server's FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx) clause
- [MS Access: Exporting to XML](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA010345611033.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of a weird question -- [OPML](http://www.opml.org/spec) is an XML format with very specific definitions and requirements, it's not like just any database table would contain OPML-appropriate data.  So the easiest answer is: it depends on what's in your DB, and whether it's appropriate to express in OPML.